# How to Fix Word Office 2010 Comment Fonts Too Small to Read

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, review

I am trying to add/review comments in Review mode in a Word document and the font size is so small, initially I didn't even realize that the comments were there. Zooming in on the document does not help, enough.

How do I change the font size of comments in a review document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to turn on managing of styles for Balloon comments while reviewing.

Using [these instructions](http://www.makeitcomplete.com/node/43) will allow you to correct this issue right away.

Comment: The link is broken.